# JOptionPane showConfirmDialog with only one button

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I need to have only one button in `showConfirmDialog`.

I tried this:

```
int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Time Entered Successfully",
                   "", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

if (response == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION || response == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
{
   System.out.println("CLOSING>>>>>>");
}
```

But this shows dialog with Yes_No_option.

I want only OK button to be displayed there. Is it possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I want only OK button to be displayed there. Is it possible?

Use [showOptionDialog()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29) method.

```
    Object[] options = {"OK"};
    int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                   "Message here ","Title",
                   JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                   JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                   null,
                   options,
                   options[0]);
```

Answer (score 24):

try using this, it creates only one button

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Loading Complete...!!!");
```

Answer (score 16):

It's the `JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION`

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                "MESSAGE",
                "TITLE",
                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```