# Why does nothing happen when a "if ... <=0" criteria is met?

Tags: java

I have a player controlled object which is set to 100 health. With each hit from an enemy it goes down. The problem is, after it reaches 0 health, it still keeps going further into the negatives. I have a popup set

```
private void playerHealth(){
    if (player.health <= 0)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you lose");
        System.exit(0);
}
```

so that in theory, it should pop up after health is <=0. However, when I try to run it, it just opens and closes immediately. I can see the window for a split second. If I delete the

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you lose");
        System.exit(0);
```

and replace it with say,

```
player.isAlive = false;
```

(isAlive is set true for player, enemies and all bullets), the health will continue to decrease past the negatives.

This part might help as well: Its the code to delete the dead enemies and bullets, there is nothing similar for player, so that may be the problem.

```
private void removeDead(){
    for (int i = 0; i <bullets.size(); i++){
        if (bullets.get(i).isAlive == false )
            bullets.remove(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <mobs.size(); i++){
        if (mobs.get(i).isAlive == false )
            mobs.remove(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <mobBullets.size(); i++){
        if (mobBullets.get(i).isAlive == false )
            mobBullets.remove(i);
    }


    bullets.trimToSize();
    mobs.trimToSize();
    mobBullets.trimToSize();
}
```

So any help is appreciated. Thank you. (all the code is from an online tutorial, which is why I dont know anything.)

Comment: add an action listener on your current joptionpane and then add system.exit(0) in its action performed... i.e. either on mouse click of ok or mouse click on closing...

Comment: Examine Eran answer. Also all loops in `removeDead` method isn't correct. Use `Iterator` for loop and remove.

Comment: @alex2410 I dont know how to do that. Ive honestly just done a "sing along" with an online tutorial which I thought would help me understand Java a bit more. It did, so it accomplished that, and Ive got it working on a level which I am more than content with. Maybe in the future if I learn more about Java I will come back and clean it up, but for now, it does everything I wanted it to, and Im fine with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want both statements to be executed, surround them in a block :

```
private void playerHealth() {
    if (player.health <= 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you lose");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Without the curly braces, `System.exit(0);` is not part of the if statement and will always be executed, which explains the `it just opens and closes immediately.`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30729694/1798593).

However, you need to know how to avoid such problems in the future. Use an IDE or other editor that will automatically indent your code for you. Here is what one did to the failing if-statement:

```
  private void playerHealth() {
    if (player.health <= 0)
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you lose");
    System.exit(0);
  }
```

The problem becomes much more obvious.

Comment: Right, I understand that is what Ill need to do in the future. Im just starting out, and all of this is helping me become a better programmer. Im not looking for a job in the field or anything, I just thought it might be a fun hobby to pick up. All this will help me get better at that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you missed a { on your if statement, if you want to execute a block of code in an if statement you need to do

```
if(something){ 
response;
}
```

So it should be this:

```
private void playerHealth() {
    if (player.health <= 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you lose");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```